# Kafka : sendOffsetsToTransaction with multiple consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

For a Kafka project, i use the consume/process/produce model but with two consumers. So I wonder, if it is possible to use `sendOffsetsToTransaction()` function for two consumers with a unique producer ?

Comment: Why do you want 2 consumers when you can subscribe to multiple topics in one consumer itself?

Comment: If I want to poll for a message during a specific time period in a topic and another time period for the second, is it possible ?

Comment: Can you poll them infinitely but process some messages at some time and another set of messages at another time? Is it feasible for you?

Comment: In fact, the problem is that the first topic is not empty, but the second one can potentially be. It depends on when the node (consumer/process/producer node) will be active and it depends on a kind of upstream node too

Comment: If one of the topic is empty, you will not be consuming any messages from it and hence there can be no processing. When once the messages come to the second topic, you can schedule them to be processed later and commit them.

Comment: The second topic is dependent on the first one. Actually, what i'm doing is a kind of consumer that consume from an upstream stage (which is a first topic), then i want to check a state value in a second topic. The problem is i'm not sure if there are messages in the second topic (if I execute for the first time for instance).

Comment: You can always subscribe to multiple topics with a single consumer and use `pause()`/`resume()` to stop/start fetching data for specific partitions. Would this help?

Comment: Ok I guess I will use the one consumer method with two topics. But how to synchronize their offsets with transaction ?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, is currently not supported. However, there is a ticket that addresses this limitation: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9953